# Store Always Encrypted Mater Key on-premises Centralize Key Vault

Tags: sql-server, security

In [SQL-Server's Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) feature, is there a way to store the Master Key in a Centralized Key Vault?

I know I can use [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) or [Local Windows Key Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccng/key-storage-and-retrieval). But I was looking for another option to have it outside the server. For example, [Symantec Encryption Management Server](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/fact_sheets/b-encryption-management-server.pdf)(pdf).

Comment: You need to give us a lot more to go on. What are the keys for? What uses them? How would they be accessed?

Comment: I'm talking about SQL Server Always Encrypted Feature. I want to store the Master Key on a Centralize Key Vault and have IIS accessing the key from there. I know I can User Azure Key Vault or Local Windows Key Store. But I was looking for another option to have it outsite the server like for example  Symantec Encryption Management Server

Comment: You should be able to get an answer at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok I will try there, thanks!